# How to merge the content of a pandas column that makes two rows distinct?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains some rows that are equal with regard to all but one column, how could I merge the content of that one column they are not equal to each other

The question sounds complicated but here's what I have:

```
   col_a   col_b   col_c
   1       2       3,4,5
   1       2       3,6
   1       3       5
```

And what I want:

```
   col_a   col_b   col_c
   1       2       3,4,5,6
   1       3       5
```

Since row 1 and row 2 only differ in col_c, I want to simply merge the two rows. But row 3 also differs in col_a, therefore it must stay the same.

Any ideas how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def group(x):
    data = []
    for i in x:
        for v in i.split(","):
            if v not in data:
                data.append(v)
    return ",".join(data)


x = df.groupby(["col_a", "col_b"], as_index=False).agg({"col_c": group})
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   col_a  col_b    col_c
0      1      2  3,4,5,6
1      1      3        5
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try `split` and `explode` followed by `drop_duplicates`:

```
df['col_c'] = df['col_c'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode('col_c').drop_duplicates()
df = df.groupby(['col_a', 'col_b'], as_index=False).agg({'col_c': ','.join})
```

Assuming the values in `col_c` are not always in sorted order, but sorted order is needed use `sort_values`:

```py
df['col_c'] = df['col_c'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode('col_c').drop_duplicates().sort_values('col_c')
df = df.groupby(['col_a', 'col_b'], as_index=False).agg({'col_c': ','.join})
```

`df`:

```
   col_a  col_b    col_c
0      1      2  3,4,5,6
1      1      3        5
```

---

An apply option using pandas functions:

```py
out = (
    df.groupby(['col_a', 'col_b'], as_index=False).agg({
        'col_c': lambda x: ','.join(x.str.split(',')
                                    .apply(pd.Series)
                                    .stack()
                                    .unique())
    })
)
```

Assuming the values in `col_c` are not always in sorted order, but sorted order is needed pass through [np.sort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html#numpy-ndarray-sort):

```py
out = (
    df.groupby(['col_a', 'col_b'], as_index=False).agg({
        'col_c': lambda x: ','.join(np.sort(x.str.split(',')
                                            .apply(pd.Series)
                                            .stack()
                                            .unique()))
    })
)
```